# Sensitivity of OpenLayers touch pointermove / click

Tags: openlayers, events

We don't want selection and highlight to happen on pan and pinch inputs but only with click events.

However, we are having a hard time to trigger the click event on touch screens. Any more than the slightest touch will trigger the pointermove / pan event.

Is it possible to alter the sensitivity of the touch pointermove event trigger?

We would like to trigger the pointermove only after a few hundred milliseconds and not immediately.

Comment: The map has a `moveTolerance` option https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html which defaults to 1 pixel.  You can specifying something larger

Comment: @Mike Amazing. Exactly what I was looking for. You want to put this down as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map has a `moveTolerance` option https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html which defaults to 1 pixel. You can try specifying something larger.